# Lost my one reputation after downvoting an answer

Tags: discussion, support

I downvoted an answer posted for [Lost 1 reputation for downvoting](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8136/is-it-a-sin-to-pay-interest/9491#9491), I just want to get myself clarified for the loss of reputation.

**1.** Did i lost 1 reputation for downvoting or is it i lost 1 reputation because i didnt  commented on the downvote.

**2.** I also made certain edits to a answer posted to this question [Lost 1 reputation for editing the answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8136/is-it-a-sin-to-pay-interest/9491#9491) , according to me those edits were logically and technically correct which i made, but is it that the peer who reviews it thought it was unneeded and hence i lost my 1 reputation.

Comment: one rep :)) lol

Comment: @Islam yes man...so valuable and hardly earned 1 reputation. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Downvoting an answer will deduct one point of reputation, regardless of whether there's a comment left or not.  This is by design to prevent gaming of the system: The penalty is not enough to discourage people from downvoting when a post legitimately needs it, but it does discourage people from downvoting for petty or selfish reasons.  See also relevant meta.SO post here: [Why do you lose reputation for down-voting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15863/132874)
2. Having a suggested edit approved will gain two reputation, but there is [no reputation penalty if the suggestion is rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78129/132874).  It's possible that you lost reputation for a different reason at that same time (e.g. a downvote on an unrelated post, or a post being deleted which you had previously gained reputation on).  The [reputation tab on your user profile](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/3028/sam-m?tab=reputation) will display breakdown your reputation changes, including the reason for the change.

Comment: ok @goldPseudo, now got where i lost my so valuable one reputation :), but one more thing i need to ask is irrespective of how bad or off topic or say vulgar in terms of language the question is, if i downvote to it i will loose my 1 reputation?.

Comment: @SamM Only answers deduct one point from the downvoter; [downvoting questions is always free](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).

Comment: great.cheers.now i can atleast downvote to some horribly language used question

Comment: @SamM try correcting the question to what you want to look it like rather than downvoting on the basis of looks

Comment: @Islam but there are certain answers that are either not up to the mark, off topic or really unneeded which deserves to be downvoted.